# Number of occurrences of a substring in a string

Tags: python, python-2.7, substring

I need to count the nunber of times the substring `'bob'` occurs in a string.

Example problem:  Find the number of times 'bob' occurs in string s such that

```
"s = xyzbobxyzbobxyzbob"  #(here there are three occurrences)
```

Here is my code:

```
s = "xyzbobxyzbobxyzbob"

numBobs = 0

while(s.find('bob') >= 0)
   numBobs = numBobs + 1
   print numBobs
```

Since the find function in Python is supposed to return -1 if a substring is unfound the while loop ought to end after printing out the incremented number of bobs each time it finds the substring.

However the program turns out to be an infinite loop when I run it.

Comment: How many `bob`s are there in `bobob`?

Comment: It should be important you understand *why* it's an infinite loop... It means the condition is always true... then you go from there...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do `s.find('bob')` you search from the beginning, so you end-up finding the same bob again and again, you need to change your search position to end of the bob you found.

`string.find` takes start argument which you can pass to tell it from where to start searching, `string.find` also return the position are which it found bob, so you can use that, add length of bob to it and pass it to next `s.find`.

So at start of loop set `start=0` as you want to search from start, inside loop if `find` returns a non-negative number you should add length of search string to it to get new start:

```
srch = 'bob'
start = numBobs = 0 while start >= 0:
    pos = s.find(srch, start)
    if pos < 0:
      break
    numBobs += 1
    start = pos + len(srch)
```

Here I am assuming that overlapped search string are not considered

Answer (score 10):

For this job, `str.find` isn't very efficient.  Instead, [`str.count`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#str.count) should be what you use:

```
>>> s = 'xyzbobxyzbobxyzbob'
>>> s.count('bob')
3
>>> s.count('xy')
3
>>> s.count('bobxyz')
2
>>>
```

---

Or, if you want to get overlapping occurrences, you can use Regex:

```
>>> from re import findall
>>> s = 'bobobob'
>>> len(findall('(?=bob)', s))
3
>>> s = "bobob"
>>> len(findall('(?=bob)', s))
2
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

`find` doesn't remember where the previous match was and start from there, not unless you tell it to. You need to keep track of the match location and pass in the optional `start` parameter. If you don't `find` will just find the first `bob` over and over.

```
find(...)
    S.find(sub [,start [,end]]) -> int

    Return the lowest index in S where substring sub is found,
    such that sub is contained within s[start:end].  Optional
    arguments start and end are interpreted as in slice notation.

    Return -1 on failure.
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that returns number of **overlapping** sub-strings without using Regex:
(Note: the 'while' loop here is written presuming you are looking for a 3-character sub-string i.e. 'bob')

```
bobs = 0
start = 0
end = 3
while end <= len(s) + 1 and start < len(s)-2 :
    if s.count('bob', start,end) == 1:
        bobs += 1
    start += 1
    end += 1

print(bobs)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you have an easy function for the task:

```
def countBob(s):
number=0
while s.find('Bob')>0:
    s=s.replace('Bob','',1)
    number=number+1        
return number
```

Then, you ask countBob whenever you need it:

```
countBob('This Bob runs faster than the other Bob dude!')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def count_substring(string, sub_string):
count=a=0
while True:
    a=string.find(sub_string)
    string=string[a+1:]
    if a>=0:
        count=count+1;
    else:
        break
return count
```

Comment: It's much more helpful if you include some explanation with your answer. How is this code different, why/how does it work and fix the OP's original issue.